# How to deploy gatsby site on netlify, if it is nested into a folder inside the repo?

Tags: gitlab, gatsby, netlify

I have to deploy a gatsby site on netlify for my university. I have a repo on gitlab with two subfolders, both being seperate gatsby projects. The deployment fails, I think because it tries to deploy the master folder, which is not a gatsby project. I inserted "npm run build" for the Build command and "gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/public" into the Publish directory. Is that the correct way to tell netlify that it should deploy the gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay folder, with gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay being one of the repos subfolders?

I get the following Deploy log:

```
10:52:27 PM: Build ready to start
10:52:29 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
10:52:29 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
10:52:29 PM: buildbot version: 16db6527b4cafa2553c3f3f11aa8d1b46a72ff40
10:52:30 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:52:30 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
10:52:30 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:52:31 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
10:52:31 PM: git clone git@gitlab.com:[deleted by me!]
10:52:32 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:52:32 PM: Found netlify.toml. Overriding site configuration
10:52:32 PM: Starting build script
10:52:32 PM: Installing dependencies
10:52:34 PM: Downloading and installing node v10.16.3...
10:52:34 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3-linux-x64.tar.xz...
10:52:34 PM: 
#####
10:52:34 PM:                                  7.6%
10:52:34 PM: 
#########################################
10:52:34 PM: ########################         90.4%
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: #
10:52:34 PM: ########################
10:52:34 PM: ############ 100.0%
10:52:34 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
10:52:35 PM: Checksums matched!
10:52:37 PM: Now using node v10.16.3 (npm v6.9.0)
10:52:37 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
10:52:39 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
10:52:39 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
10:52:39 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:52:39 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:52:39 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.9.0
10:53:08 PM: > sharp@0.22.1 install /opt/build/repo/gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/node_modules/sharp
10:53:08 PM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
10:53:09 PM: info
10:53:09 PM: sharp
10:53:09 PM:  Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.4/libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
10:53:11 PM: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /opt/build/repo/gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/node_modules/core-js
10:53:11 PM: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
10:53:11 PM: Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
10:53:11 PM: The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
10:53:11 PM: > https://opencollective.com/core-js 
10:53:11 PM: > https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 
10:53:11 PM: Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)
10:53:11 PM: > core-js-pure@3.1.4 postinstall /opt/build/repo/gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/node_modules/core-js-pure
10:53:11 PM: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
10:53:11 PM: Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
10:53:11 PM: The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
10:53:11 PM: > https://opencollective.com/core-js 
10:53:11 PM: > https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 
10:53:11 PM: Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)
10:53:12 PM: > gatsby-telemetry@1.1.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry
10:53:12 PM: > node src/postinstall.js
10:53:14 PM: npm
10:53:14 PM:  WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
10:53:14 PM: npm
10:53:14 PM:  WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
10:53:14 PM: added 1591 packages from 877 contributors and audited 21387 packages in 33.175s
10:53:14 PM: found 529 vulnerabilities (527 high, 2 critical)
10:53:14 PM:   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
10:53:14 PM: NPM modules installed
10:53:14 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
10:53:14 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
10:53:14 PM: unset GOOS;
10:53:14 PM: unset GOARCH;
10:53:14 PM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64';
10:53:14 PM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.12.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
10:53:14 PM: go version >&2;
10:53:14 PM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.12.linux.amd64.env';
10:53:14 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
10:53:14 PM: Installing missing commands
10:53:14 PM: Verify run directory
10:53:14 PM: Executing user command: npm run build
10:53:14 PM: > @oddstronaut/gatsby-starter-tailwind@3.0.25 build /opt/build/repo/gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay
10:53:14 PM: > yarn run clean && gatsby build
10:53:14 PM: sh: 1: yarn: not found
10:53:14 PM: npm
10:53:14 PM:  ERR! file sh
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR! errno
10:53:14 PM:  ENOENT
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR! syscall spawn
10:53:14 PM: npm
10:53:14 PM:  ERR! @oddstronaut/gatsby-starter-tailwind@3.0.25 build: `yarn run clean && gatsby build`
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR!
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the @oddstronaut/gatsby-starter-tailwind@3.0.25 build script.
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
10:53:14 PM: npm
10:53:14 PM:  ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:53:14 PM: npm ERR!
10:53:14 PM:      /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2019-10-03T20_53_14_985Z-debug.log
10:53:14 PM: Skipping functions preparation step: no functions directory set
10:53:14 PM: Caching artifacts
10:53:14 PM: Started saving node modules
10:53:15 PM: Finished saving node modules
10:53:15 PM: Started saving pip cache
10:53:15 PM: Finished saving pip cache
10:53:15 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Started saving go dependencies
10:53:15 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
10:53:17 PM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:53:17 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:53:17 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:53:18 PM: Finished processing build request in 48.202499427s
```

[image: Root:]

[image: However if I go into the gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay folder there is no public folder, but it is definitely there in my cloned repo on my PC!]

However if I go into the gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay folder there is no public folder, but it is definitely there in my cloned repo on my PC! Not being super experienced with git, is that supposed to be. It is the same for a repo with just the default gatsby starter page, which i can deploy just fine, so i think its supposed to be that way?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netlify: How do you deploy sites that are nested in a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364932/netlify-how-do-you-deploy-sites-that-are-nested-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add a [`netlify.toml`](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/#getting-started) file in your repository root?

```
# Settings in the [build] context are global and are applied to all contexts
# unless otherwise overridden by more specific contexts.
[build]
  # Directory to change to before starting a build.
  # This is where we will look for package.json/.nvmrc/etc.
  base = "gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/"

  # Directory (relative to root of your repo) that contains the deploy-ready
  # HTML files and assets generated by the build. If a base directory has
  # been specified, include it in the publish directory path.
  publish = "gatsbyjs-starter-tailwindplay/public/"

  # Default build command.
  command = "npm run build"
```

The `public` and `.cache` folders are created as a result of gatsby's build process. They are set to be ignored by git in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: does not work unfortunately, I added the deploy log above

Comment: Can you please add your `package.json` too?